# How to fix the asynchronous nature of my appending function?

Tags: swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, parse-server

I have a query set up to pull data from a database (Parse-server hosted by heroku) and append it to an array; within this query is another query that is used to pull info from a different class but also used to append another array. I think because I use `.findObjectsinBackground` it happens asynchronously, which leads to an issue. Here is the code (generalized):

```
    func getQueries(completion: (() -> Void)?){

        let searchQuery = PFQuery(className: "Etc")         
        searchQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in

            if let objectss = objects{

                for object in objectss {
                    //append some arrays
                    let otherQuery = PFQuery(className: "OtherClass")
                    otherQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: object["User"] as String)
                    otherQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: {(objects, error) in
                        if let objectss = objects{
                            for object in objectss{
                                array.append(object["ProfPic"] as PFFile)
                                print("\(array) and its count is \(array.count)") //this returns a non 0 value
                            }
                        }
                        completion!()
                    })

            print("\(array) and its count is \(array.count)") //this returns 0
                }
            }
         })
    }
```

`array`'s count is returned as non 0 once it has been appended in its own closure, but returned as 0 outside of its closure. This is a problem since the arrays are used in iterating through to display information. Is there anyway to make sure before the overall closure of `searchQuery` is done, the `otherQuery`'s append is already complete?
(Also, the fact that it is happening asynchronously causing the problem is a guess... I could be wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the later case, you are printing the count bofore the data is fetched, e.g. outside the completion block of `findObjectsInBackground`.

You can wrap the whole thing in an own method with completion block:

```
func fetchData(_ completion: () -> Void) {

    searchQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
        guard let objectss = objects else {
            completion() 
        }

        for object in objectss {
            let otherQuery = PFQuery(className: "OtherClass")
            otherQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: object["User"] as String)
            otherQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: {(objects, error) in

                guard let objectss = objects else {
                    completion()
                }

                for object in objectss{
                    array.append(object["ProfPic"] as PFFile)
                }

                print("In loop: \(array) and its count is \(array.count)")                
                completion()
            })
        }
    })
}
```

And than all it like this:

```
fetchData() {
     print("After completing: \(array) and its count is \(array.count)")
    // do stuff with your fetched data and display it
    // "use in iterating through to display information" here
}
```

---

Update:

In your updated question you are callin `completion!()` in success case only. You have to call it in any case:

```
...
if let objectss = objects 
    ...
    completion!()
} else {
    completion!()
} 
...
```

Comment: shallowThought, I tried to do what you suggested (look at the edited question code block... I put the `completion!()` in there... it was always wrapped in a function, I just hadn't shown that bit). However, the second print statement is still returning 0. Any ideas?

Comment: As written, you are printing the count before the data is fetched. Put your `print()` statement inside your completion block (or before your `completion!()` call). As in my edited answer.